# Add timestamp in Powershell output

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have the following code that export a CSV-file from a query.
How do I add a "Get-date" (today) stamp in the end of the file in the filepath?

```
$ds.Tables[0] | Export-csv -delimiter ";" -path "C:\temp\TempWarehousingControl.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Force -Encoding UTF8 
Get-Content C:\temp\TempWarehousingControl.csv | %{ $_ -replace """""", "NULL"} |%{ $_ -replace """", ""} | out-file -FilePath C:\Batch\Output\WarehousingControl\WarehousingControl.csv -Force -Encoding utf8
```

Comment: What do you mean? Append a timestamp to the CSV file itself or its name?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you meant "how do I add today's date to the end of the filepath" (vs the end of the file), this will do it:

```
"C:\Batch\Output\WarehousingControl\WarehousingControl-$(get-date -Format 'dd-MM-yyyy').csv"
```

**Included in your full code:**

```
$ds.Tables[0] | Export-csv -delimiter ";" -path "C:\temp\TempWarehousingControl.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Force -Encoding UTF8 
Get-Content C:\temp\TempWarehousingControl.csv | %{ $_ -replace """""", "NULL"} |%{ $_ -replace """", ""} | out-file -FilePath "C:\Batch\Output\WarehousingControl\WarehousingControl-$(get-date -Format 'dd-MM-yyyy').csv" -Force -Encoding utf8
```

**Explanation:**

This is a subexpression $() which uses `get-date` to get the current date and formats it as dd-MM-yyyy (note month is a capital M as lowercase m is the code for minute).

Comment: Thanks! I do though get a syntax error on the last line. 
I've wrote it like this: 
Get-Content C:\TEMP\TransactionsControl\TempLargeWithdrawals.csv | %{ $_ -replace """""", "NULL"} |%{ $_ -replace """", ""} | out-file -FilePath "C:\Batch\Output\WarehousingControl\LargeWithdrawals-$(get-date -Format "dd-MM-yyyy").csv" -Force -Encoding utf8

Comment: Sorry should have used single quotes around the dd-MM-yyyy part. Try this: "C:\Batch\Output\WarehousingControl\WarehousingControl-$(get-date -Format 'dd-MM-yyyy').csv"

Comment: Still syntax error :/. Something else that might be incorrect?

Comment: Hmm Where can I see that? It only says, "Syntax error on line 48", i.e. that line!

Comment: There should be several lines of error text including a line that points to where the error is. Perhaps add a screenshot to your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$path = "C:\Batch\Output\WarehousingControl\WarehousingControl.csv"
$path = $path.Replace(".csv", "_" + (Get-Date -f "yyy-MM-dd") + ".csv")

$ds.Tables[0] | 
    Export-csv -delimiter ";" -path "C:\temp\TempWarehousingControl.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Force -Encoding UTF8 

Get-Content C:\temp\TempWarehousingControl.csv | 
    %{ $_ -replace """""", "NULL"} |
    %{ $_ -replace """", ""} | 
    Out-File -FilePath $path -Force -Encoding utf8
```